Manual Django form not saving no matter what I do to Postgres database
I have a problem with saving a form to the database. Everything I've tried doesn't work and I really don't know what else to do.
I have a manual form created in Django, I get absolutely no errors on save, everything works fine without any errors, I even get redirected to the success page, and yet I have absolutely nothing in the database.
# models.py

class Lead(Model):
    lead_status = CharField(choices=STATUS, default='Activă', verbose_name='Status cerere')
    property_type = CharField(choices=TIP_PROPRIETATE, default='Apartament', verbose_name='Tip cerere')
    transaction_type = CharField(choices=TIP_TRANZACTIE, verbose_name='Tip tranzacție')

    contact = ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name='Contact asociat')

    county = CharField(choices=JUDETE, verbose_name='Județ')
    city = CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Localitate')
    zone = CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Zonă')
    street = CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Stradă')

    budget = IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Buget alocat')
    payment_method = CharField(choices=MODALITATE_PLATA, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Modalitate plată', )

    urgency = CharField(choices=URGENTA, default='Normal', verbose_name='Urgență')
    other_details = TextField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Alte detalii')

    labels = CharField(choices=ETICHETA, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Etichete')
    notes = TextField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Notițe proprii')

    created_at = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Data introducerii')
    updated_at = DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Data ultimei actualizări')
    deadline_date = DateField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Data limită')
    deadline_time = TimeField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Ora limită')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.contact}'


class ApartmentLead(Lead):
    apartment_type = CharField(choices=TIP_APARTAMENT, verbose_name='Tip apartament')
    destination = CharField(choices=DESTINATIE_AP, verbose_name='Destinație')

    rooms_number = IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Număr camere')
    nr_bedrooms = IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Număr dormitoare')
    nr_bathrooms = IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Număr băi')
    bathroom_window = BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Geam la baie')
    floor = CharField(choices=ETAJ_AP, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Etaj')
    excluded_ground_floor = BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Exclus parter')
    excluded_top_floor = BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Exclus ultimul etaj')
    nr_floors = IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Număr etaje')

    minimal_surface = DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Suprafață minimă (mp)')
    construction_status = CharField(choices=STADIU_CONSTRUCTIE, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Stadiu construcție')
    furniture = CharField(choices=MOBILIER, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Mobilier')
    comfort = CharField(choices=CONFORT, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Confort')
    ap_compart = CharField(choices=COMPARTIMENTARE_AP, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Compartimentare')
    orientation = CharField(choices=ORIENTARE, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Orientare')
    interior_finishes = CharField(choices=FINISAJE, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Stare interior')
    construction_year = IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Anul construcției')

    basement = BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Subsol')
    semi_basement = BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Demisol')
    technical_floor = BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Etaj tehnic')
    loft = BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Mansardă')
    attic = BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Pod')
    elevator = BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Lift')

    created_by = ForeignKey(User, on_delete=SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='my_apartment_key', verbose_name='Agent asociat')
    assigned_listings = ForeignKey(Apartment, on_delete=SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                   related_name='assigned_apartment_key', verbose_name='Proprietăți asociate')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.apartment_type} - {self.created_by}'

# forms.py

class LeadCreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'status': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'property_type': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'transaction_type': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),

            'contact': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),

            'county': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'city': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'zone': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'street': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),

            'budget': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'payment_method': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),

            'urgency': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'other_details': Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': '3'}),

            'labels': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'notes': Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': '3'}),

            'created_at': DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'updated_at': DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'deadline_date': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
            'deadline_time': TimeInput(attrs={'type': 'time', 'step': '600'})
        }


class ApartmentLeadCreateForm(LeadCreateForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ApartmentLead
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'apartment_type': SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'destination': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),

            'rooms_number': NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'nr_bedrooms': NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'nr_bathrooms': NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'bathroom_window': CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-check-input'}),
            'floor': SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'excluded_ground_floor': CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-check-input'}),
            'excluding_top_floor': CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-check-input'}),
            'nr_floors': NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),

            'minimal_surface': NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'construction_status': SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'furniture': SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'comfort': SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'ap_compart': SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'orientation': SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'interior_finishes': SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'construction_year': NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),

            'basement': CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-check-input'}),
            'semi_basement': CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-check-input'}),
            'technical_floor': CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-check-input'}),
            'loft': CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-check-input'}),
            'attic': CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-check-input'}),
            'elevator': CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-check-input'}),

            'assigned_listings': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()

        rooms_number = cleaned_data.get('rooms_number')
        bedrooms_number = cleaned_data.get('nr_bedrooms')

        if bedrooms_number is not None and rooms_number is not None and bedrooms_number > rooms_number:
            raise ValidationError('Numărul de dormitoare nu poate fi mai mare decât numărul total de camere.')

        floor = cleaned_data.get('floor')
        nr_floors = cleaned_data.get('nr_floors')

        if floor is not None and nr_floors is not None and floor > nr_floors:
            raise ValidationError('Numărul etajului apartamentului nu poate fi mai mare decât numărul total de etaje.')

        return cleaned_data

# urls.py

app_name = 'leads'

urlpatterns = [
    path('add-apartment-lead', ApartmentLeadCreateView.as_view(), name='add_apartment_lead'),
]

# views.py

class ApartmentLeadCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = ApartmentLead
    form_class = ApartmentLeadCreateForm
    template_name = 'leads/apartments/add_apartment_lead.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('leads:lead_added')
    permission_required = 'leads.add_apartmentlead'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        stored_contact = self.request.session.get('storedContactId')
        stored_type = self.request.session.get('storedType')
        context['storedContactId'] = stored_contact
        context['storedType'] = stored_type
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_at = timezone.now()
        form.instance.updated_at = timezone.now()
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user

        try:
            response = super().form_valid(form)
            return response
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Eroare în timpul salvării datelor: {e}")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

# HTML & JavaScript

{% extends 'partials/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %} Cerere nouă | Apartament {% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    
    {% block pagetitle %}
        {% include "partials/page_title.html" with pagetitle="Cereri" title="Cerere nouă | Apartament" %}
    {% endblock pagetitle %}
    
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        {% if perms.leads.add_apartmentlead %}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <form id="add_lead_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="row" 
                                  action="{% url 'leads:add_apartment_lead' %}">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="card">
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <div id="contactInfo">
                                                <h5><span id="firstName"></span> <span id="lastName"></span></h5>
                                                <div id="phoneNumber"></div>
                                                <div id="email"></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <input id="contact" name="contact" type="hidden" value="{{ storedContactId }}" 
                                                   required>
                                            <hr class="border-secondary-subtle">
                                            <div class="col-lg-12 mb-3">
                                                <label for="property_type" class="form-label">Tip cerere <span 
                                                        class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                <input id="property_type" class="form-control text-muted" 
                                                       name="property_type" value="{{ storedType }}" readonly required>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-12 mb-3">
                                                <label for="apartment_type" class="form-label">
                                                    Tip apartament <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                <select id="apartment_type" class="form-select" name="apartment_type" 
                                                        required>
                                                    {% for value, label in form.fields.apartment_type.choices %}
                                                        <option value="{{ value }}">{{ label }}</option>
                                                    {% endfor %}
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-12 mb-3">
                                                <label for="transaction_type" class="form-label">Tip tranzacție <span
                                                        class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                <select id="transaction_type" class="form-select" name="transaction_type" 
                                                        required>
                                                    {% for value, label in form.fields.transaction_type.choices %}
                                                        <option value="{{ value }}">{{ label }}</option>
                                                    {% endfor %}
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                <label for="lead_status" class="form-label">Status cerere <span
                                                        class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                <select id="lead_status" class="form-select" name="lead_status" required>
                                                    {% for value, label in form.fields.lead_status.choices %}
                                                        <option value="{{ value }}">{{ label }}</option>
                                                    {% endfor %}
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <hr class="border-secondary-subtle">
                                            <div class="col-lg-12 mb-3">
                                                <label for="county" class="form-label">Județ <span
                                                        class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                <select id="county" class="form-control" name="county" data-choices 
                                                        required>
                                                    {% for value, label in form.fields.county.choices %}
                                                        <option value="{{ value }}">{{ label }}</option>
                                                    {% endfor %}
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-12 mb-3">
                                                <label for="city" class="form-label">Localitate <span
                                                        class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                <input id="city" class="form-control" name="city" type="text" required>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-12 mb-3">
                                                <label for="zone" class="form-label">Zonă</label>
                                                <input id="zone" class="form-control" name="zone" type="text">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                <label for="street" class="form-label">Stradă</label>
                                                <input id="street" class="form-control" name="street" type="text">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="card">
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <div class="col-lg-12 mb-3">
                                                <label for="budget" class="form-label">Buget alocat</label>
                                                <input id="budget" class="form-control" name="budget" type="text">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-12 mb-3">
                                                <label for="payment_method" class="form-label">Metodă de plată</label>
                                                <select id="payment_method" class="form-select" name="payment_method">
                                                    {% for value, label in form.fields.payment_method.choices %}
                                                        <option value="{{ value }}">{{ label }}</option>
                                                    {% endfor %}
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <hr class="border-secondary-subtle">
                                            <div class="col-lg-12 mb-3">
                                                <label for="urgency" class="form-label">Urgență</label>
                                                <select id="urgency" class="form-select" name="urgency">
                                                    {% for value, label in form.fields.urgency.choices %}
                                                        {% if value == "Normal" %}
                                                            <option value="{{ value }}" selected>{{ label }}</option>
                                                        {% else %}
                                                            <option value="{{ value }}">{{ label }}</option>
                                                        {% endif %}
                                                    {% endfor %}
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-12 mb-3">
                                                <label for="deadline_date" class="form-label">Data limită</label>
                                                <input id="deadline_date" class="form-control" name="deadline_date" 
                                                       type="date" placeholder="ZZ.LL.AAAA">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-12 mb-3">
                                                <label for="deadline_time" class="form-label">Ora limită</label>
                                                <input id="deadline_time" class="form-control" name="deadline_time" 
                                                       type="time" step="600" placeholder="OO:MM">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-12 mb-3">
                                                <label for="assigned_listings" class="form-label">
                                                    Proprietăți asociate</label>
                                                <select id="assigned_listings" class="form-control" 
                                                        name="assigned_listings" multiple>
                                                    {% for value, label in form.fields.assigned_listings.choices %}
                                                        <option value="{{ value }}"></option>
                                                    {% endfor %}
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-12 mb-3">
                                                <label for="labels" class="form-label">Etichete</label>
                                                <select id="labels" class="form-select" name="labels" multiple>
                                                    {% for value, label in form.fields.labels.choices %}
                                                        <option value="{{ value }}"></option>
                                                    {% endfor %}
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                <label for="notes" class="form-label">Notițe proprii</label>
                                                <textarea id="notes" class="form-control" name="notes" type="text" 
                                                          rows="4"></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-footer">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-subtle-success float-end">
                                                Salvează cererea
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}

{% endblock content %}

{% block extra_javascript %}
    
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            console.log('Conținutul DOM a fost încărcat.');
            
            var storedType = sessionStorage.getItem('selectedType');
            var storedContactId = sessionStorage.getItem('selectedContact');
            
            console.log('Tip cerere:', storedType);
            console.log('ID contact:', storedContactId);
            
            if (document.getElementById('property_type')) {
                document.getElementById('property_type').value = storedType;
            }
            if (document.getElementById('contact')) {
                document.getElementById('contact').value = storedContactId;
            }
            
            if (storedContactId) {
                fetch('/contacts/api/contact-details/' + storedContactId)
                    .then(response => {
                        if (!response.ok) {
                            throw new Error('Eroare la solicitarea datelor contactului!');
                        }
                        return response.json();
                    })
                    .then(data => {
                        document.getElementById('firstName').innerText = data.first_name;
                        document.getElementById('lastName').innerText = data.last_name;
                        document.getElementById('phoneNumber').innerText = data.phone_number;
                        document.getElementById('email').innerText = data.email;
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error('Eroare:', error);
                    });
            }
            
            var leadAssignedListings = document.getElementById('assigned_listings');
            new Choices(leadAssignedListings, {
                allowHTML: true,
                loadingText: 'Se încarcă...',
                noResultsText: 'Nu există proprietăți disponibile.'
            });
            
            var leadLabels = document.getElementById('labels');
            new Choices(leadLabels, {
                allowHTML: true,
                loadingText: 'Se încarcă...',
                noResultsText: 'Nu există alte etichete.'
            });
            
            document.getElementById('add_lead_form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                
                var formData = new FormData(this);
                
                console.log('Datele trimise sunt:', formData);
                
                fetch('/leads/add-apartment-lead', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formData,
                })
                .then(response => {
                    if (!response.ok) {
                        throw new Error('A apărut o eroare în timpul salvării.');
                    }
                    return response.text();
                })
                .then(data => {
                    console.log('Datele au fost salvate cu succes:', data);
                    window.location.href = 'lead-added';
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Eroare în timpul salvării:', error);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    
{% endblock extra_javascript %}

I also tried with {{ form }} but it still doesn't work. I note that I first select the contact and the property type on a previous page, where I save the two items to sessionStorage, but the point is that the whole form looks empty anyway, as if I actually have nothing in any field on the form.
The html file isn't complete because it's too long, but there are a lot of important fields in there so you can figure out what it's about.
Thanks in advance and I appreciate any help!

Where are you saving the new record?

I forgot to mention that I'm only a few months into programming... in a Postgres database, if I understand your question correctly

But I'm not sure if I understood your question very well

What I mean is, I don't see any statements here that are ASKING to save a record into the database.

Now I see what you mean, but the point is that anyway, as far as I know, I don't need to add an explicit statement to request the record to be saved, since this is automatically handled by "CreateView" when the form is submitted.

In your model, you have:
class Meta:
abstract = True
Unless I am missing something, it is better to remove it. If we look at the django documentation, it says

This model will then not be used to create any database table

Source: Abstract Model

I introduced that "Meta class: abstract = True" because the "Lead" class must be inherited by the "ApartmentLead" class, just as it is inherited by the "HouseLead" class, "TerrainLead" etc. (it just didn't make sense to write all the classes that inherit the "Lead" class, I wasn't allowed to write the whole HTML file anyway).   But it seems that it doesn't work anyway even if I remove "class Meta: abstract = True"

I understood. Can you try to log the form after "form.instance.created_by = self.request.user"? basically, print out the form: print(form). and then submit the form so it can be called.

I'm not sure if I understand very well, do you mean like this?
def form_valid(self, form):
form.instance.created_at = timezone.now()
form.instance.updated_at = timezone.now()
form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
print(form)
    try:
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Eroare în timpul salvării datelor: {e}")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url()) ... If that's what you mean, then nothing is printing to my console.


It is not possible to understand from the comment, but I think you got it correct.
It is a good start that it does not print anything, which means that your form comes empty from front end. So you have to check the if you render the form correctly.
Also add this your class, so you can see if there is any error:
def form_invalid:
print(form.errors)
return super().form_invalid(form)

Well, this is new:   apartment_typeSelect a valid choice. ['Apartament'] is not one of the available choices.floorSelect a valid choice. [''] is not one of the available choices.construction_statusSelect a valid choice. [''] is not one of the available choices.

So it means you are not sending correct data to the backend. You render the form incorrectly, so when form is sent, the data is being sent, but some of them not correctly. Check those fields, names and also the "choices".

I think I just figured out why my data isn't being saved to the database. It's because in forms.py I'm using "SelectMultiple" instead of "Select" for the fields above.
